# Added API key to work with Google Maps, but getting error: API key not found

Tags: android, kotlin, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps

SOLVED

java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that  is in the  element of AndroidManifest.xml

This error I'm getting despite I added meta-data tag with appropriate API_KEY.

In app I'm using Compose. GoogleMap() composable called from MapScreen.kt composable function, that called from MainActivity.kt

MapScreen:

```
package com.example.spotchecking.presentation

import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.material.FloatingActionButton
import androidx.compose.material.Icon
import androidx.compose.material.Scaffold
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ToggleOff
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.ToggleOn
import androidx.compose.material.rememberScaffoldState
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.hilt.navigation.compose.hiltViewModel
import com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMap
import dagger.hilt.android.lifecycle.HiltViewModel

@Composable
fun MapScreen (
    viewModel: MapViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val scaffoldState = rememberScaffoldState()

    Scaffold (
        scaffoldState = scaffoldState,
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Icon (
                    imageVector =
                    if (viewModel.state.isFalloutMap) {
                        Icons.Default.ToggleOff
                    } else {
                        Icons.Default.ToggleOn
                    },
                    contentDescription = "Toggle Fallout map"
                )
            }
        }
    ) {
        GoogleMap (
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentPadding = it

        )
        Box (
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(it),
        )
    }
}



@Composable
@Preview
fun MapScreenPreview() {
    MapScreen(hiltViewModel())
}
```

MainActivity:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            SpotCheckingTheme {
                MapScreen()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's my AdroidManifest.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.spotchecking">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <!-- Always include this permission -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <!-- Include only if your app benefits from precise location access. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SpotChecking"
        tools:targetApi="31">

<!--        <meta-data-->
<!--            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyC-2HlmmCmrSGC4O6CjQAxs8bRgm92L9Xw"-->
<!--            android:value="AIzaSyC-2HlmmCmrSGC4O6CjQAxs8bRgm92L9Xw" />-->
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.SpotChecking">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY"/>
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Of course instead API_KEY I'm putting my Google API key from google cloud console.

[Settings of API key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCZ4x.png)

And here's a stack trace of the error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.spotchecking, PID: 16367
    java.lang.RuntimeException: API key not found.  Check that <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY" android:value="your API key"/> is in the <application> element of AndroidManifest.xml
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.drd.p.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014026@22.50.14 (100306-0):6)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.auth.f.i(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014026@22.50.14 (100306-0):1)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.l.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014026@22.50.14 (100306-0):24)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014026@22.50.14 (100306-0):7)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.CreatorImpl.logInitialization(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014026@22.50.14 (100306-0):3)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.g.ba(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014026@22.50.14 (100306-0):5)
        at fj.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@225014026@22.50.14 (100306-0):4)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:914)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zza.zzc(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zze.zzl(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:4)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:12)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer.initialize(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzah.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzah.createDelegate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.zaf(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:6)
        at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.DeferredLifecycleHelper.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-base@@18.0.1:1)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView.onCreate(com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps@@18.1.0:4)
        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt.lifecycleObserver$lambda$11(GoogleMap.kt:199)
        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt.$r8$lambda$Vm6abttjyrD0BNPAw0a-nOgtk1E(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onStateChanged(Unknown Source:4)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.addObserver(LifecycleRegistry.java:196)
        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt$MapLifecycle$1.invoke(GoogleMap.kt:174)
        at com.google.maps.android.compose.GoogleMapKt$MapLifecycle$1.invoke(GoogleMap.kt:170)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.DisposableEffectImpl.onRemembered(Effects.kt:81)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl$RememberEventDispatcher.dispatchRememberObservers(Composition.kt:1032)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChangesInLocked(Composition.kt:793)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.applyChanges(Composition.kt:813)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.Recomposer.composeInitial$runtime_release(Recomposer.kt:827)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.ComposerImpl$CompositionContextImpl.composeInitial$runtime_release(Composer.kt:3712)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.CompositionImpl.setContent(Composition.kt:519)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcomposeInto(SubcomposeLayout.kt:468)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:441)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:432)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:421)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$Scope.subcompose(SubcomposeLayout.kt:732)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:316)
        at androidx.compose.material.ScaffoldKt$ScaffoldLayout$1$1$1.invoke(Scaffold.kt:243)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.LayoutNodeSubcompositionsState$createMeasurePolicy$1$measure$1.placeChildren(SubcomposeLayout.kt:602)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:968)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:953)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:953)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:938)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50$default(Placeable.kt:203)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.placeInBox(Box.kt:186)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt.access$placeInBox(Box.kt:1)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:126)
        at androidx.compose.foundation.layout.BoxKt$boxMeasurePolicy$1$measure$2.invoke(Box.kt:125)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:968)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:953)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:953)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:938)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:393)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:266)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:407)
        at androidx.compose.ui.graphics.SimpleGraphicsLayerModifier$measure$1.invoke(GraphicsLayerModifier.kt:406)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.ModifiedLayoutNode.placeAt-f8xVGno(ModifiedLayoutNode.kt:101)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeWithLayer-aW-9-wM(Placeable.kt:396)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:163)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelativeWithLayer(Placeable.kt:385)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelativeWithLayer$default(Placeable.kt:246)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy$measure$2.invoke(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:43)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.RootMeasurePolicy$measure$2.invoke(RootMeasurePolicy.kt:39)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.MeasureScope$layout$1.placeChildren(MeasureScope.kt:70)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:968)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode$layoutChildren$1.invoke(LayoutNode.kt:953)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:52)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.layoutChildren$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:953)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.onNodePlaced$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:938)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.InnerPlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(InnerPlaceable.kt:79)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.place-70tqf50(Placeable.kt:370)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:161)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.access$placeOuterWrapper-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:28)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:149)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable$placeAt$1.invoke(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.Snapshot$Companion.observe(Snapshot.kt:2101)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateObserver.observeReads(SnapshotStateObserver.kt:110)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:78)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at androidx.compose.ui.node.OwnerSnapshotObserver.observeLayoutModifierSnapshotReads$ui_release(OwnerSnapshotObserver.kt:59)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.OuterMeasurablePlaceable.placeAt-f8xVGno(OuterMeasurablePlaceable.kt:148)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable.access$placeAt-f8xVGno(Placeable.kt:31)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative(Placeable.kt:359)
        at androidx.compose.ui.layout.Placeable$PlacementScope.placeRelative$default(Placeable.kt:179)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.LayoutNode.place$ui_release(LayoutNode.kt:811)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:278)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.access$remeasureAndRelayoutIfNeeded(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:38)
        at androidx.compose.ui.node.MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.measureAndLayout(MeasureAndLayoutDelegate.kt:208)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AndroidComposeView.onMeasure(AndroidComposeView.android.kt:806)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24834)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.internalOnMeasure$ui_release(ComposeView.android.kt:298)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.AbstractComposeView.onMeasure(ComposeView.android.kt:285)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6975)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6975)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24834)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6975)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:773)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24834)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3237)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1994)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2297)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1882)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8047)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1041)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:860)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:785)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1026)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7563)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:994)
```

I tried to add another meta-data:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY" />
```

And tried to add 2 meta-data:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY" />
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY"/>
```

And even 3 meta-data:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY" />
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="API_KEY"/>
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem wasn't that big...

The error occurred due to incorrect meta-data tag. My tag was:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.MY_API_KEY"
            android:value="MY_API_KEY"/>
```

In both parameters I put my API key, while in the first parameter I shouldn't put it, so it must stay so:

```
android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
```

I misunderstood it and put my API key. So now it's working. Thank u everyone

Answer (score 0):

It looks like in `AndroidManifest.xml` that your `<meta-data/>` tag is commented out? I'm not sure if this is intentional or not. If so:

```
<application
        ...

<!--        <meta-data-->
<!--            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyC-2HlmmCmrSGC4O6CjQAxs8bRgm92L9Xw"-->
<!--            android:value="AIzaSyC-2HlmmCmrSGC4O6CjQAxs8bRgm92L9Xw" />-->
```

should look like this:

```
<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.AIzaSyC-2HlmmCmrSGC4O6CjQAxs8bRgm92L9Xw"
            android:value="yourApiKeyHere"/>
```

You can also try 'verifying' the API by creating a blank Android app through Android Studio with the 'Google Maps Activity' option, and just test and see your API works.

Comment: of course I know, that it's commented, I'm not that stupid. as I mentioned in the question I tried use 3 different meta-data and I left only one, that requires in error. ok, I'll try to test API key. thank u for reply.

Comment: tried to create project with MapsActivity- doesn't work, I'm getting the same error